# Securing NodeJS API

Tags: node.js

I'm using Node/Angular for creating my new web app. now that I'm near to deploy it, I have to make sure it is properly secured and only my angular app can expose to the api.

So is there any tutorial or something to follow to setup CORS, signature, header token, IP Whitelist.

**EDIT:** I'm not talking about authentication. I mean hiding my endpoints and accepting only from my angular and flutter app